# What moves affect the battle environment?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So far I've only managed to get an item from battle after using the move **Surf.** This knocked down a stone pillar that was in the background and gave me a hard stone, I believe.

I have tried a lot of other moves when I see stones, berry trees and sandpiles in the background, but can never get them drop an item. **So what all moves will affect these? Also, are they area specific?** For example will only certain berry trees be in Route "X"?

Comment: I think you should have done a quick search before asking, googling "pokemon xy background items" gives me [serebii's description page about this](http://www.serebii.net/xy/wilditems.shtml) :)

Comment: @Jerry when I looked it up a couple days ago I couldn't find anything on it. Just remembered to post my question about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several background objects that drop items when you use certain moves:

- Trees - Air Cutter, Twister, Blizzard

  - Routes 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 17, 19, Ambrette Town, Cyllage City, Azure Bay
- Grass - Razor Leaf, Petal Blizzard

  - Routes 5, 7, 10, 11, 19
- Stalagmite - Surf, Muddy Water

  - Caves
- Boulder - Rock Slide

  - Caves and routes
- Snowpile - Rock Slide, Hyper Voice

  - Route 17
- Ice Crystal - Rock Slide

  - Route 17
- Hardened Sand - Rock Slide

  - Route 9, 18
- Luminous Boulder - Rock Slide

  - Glittering Cave
- Sandpile - Rock Slide, Hyper Voice

  - Route 8, Cyllage City
- Sandpile - Heat Wave

  - Route 8, 13, 19

These background objects can all be distinguished by the fact that they are directly behind the opposing Pokemon.